# Import data from gridview to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to combine [this](http://aspsnippets.com/articles/import-data-from-excel-to-gridview-in-aspnet.aspx) with [this](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Dynamic-TextBox-values-in-GridView-to-SQL-Server-Database.aspx)?

So essentialy I want to upload an excel spreadsheet, which is then shown to me in a gridview (as in the first link). Then I should be able to save the data in the gridview to my sql-database (as in the last part in the second link).

Is this the way to do it or is there something smarter / easier ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a format in which you want to upload excel file.
2. Then upload that format with details in excel and on click event of submit save that uploaded data into database.